# Accessing derived class variable through object of base class in C#

Tags: c#

I have code as follows 
Declare.cs

```
Class B { }
Class D1 : B { public var1 }
Class D2 : B {}
B Baseobject = new B();
if(baseobject is D1){ Console.print(B.var1) }
```

When I compile this scenario I always get compiler error that `var1` is not accessible to `B`. If `var1` always needs to be in `D1` is there way to resolve this?

Comment: This will never work

Comment: @Ric instead of saying this. Please explain to an author why it won't work.

Comment: Abit of research goes a long way. This has been asked many times before and a quick search can resolve this question rather than asking it again.

Comment: Inheritance does not work that way. The parent does not know about the fields of the children

Answer (score 0):

The object needs to be an instance of D1, so your example is a bit wrong.

You then need to cast your object to D1.

```cs
B baseObject = new D1();
Console.WriteLine(((D1)baseObject).var1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it won't compile because you need to cast. Why do you need to cast? Because your object reference is a type of B and knows nothing about D1 type and its methods and properties. You need to read a bit more about basic OOP principles